# Applying filter on filtered subset results with pseudoelements in CSS

Tags: css, pseudo-element

Greetings I have this fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/partizanos/a5pf136a/.

```
tr:not(.Row--toIgnore):nth-child(even){
    background-color: #000;
}
```

Inside I have a table and CSS rules aiming to color the rows.

I would like to have the following effect:

- WhiteColor Row1 --odd===========Row1 --odd WhiteColor
- BlackColor Row2 --even==========Row2 --even BlackColor
- WhiteColor Row3 --odd--->Remove= REMOVED
- BlackColor Row4 --==============**Row4 --ODD** WhiteColor

I don't want to solve it using Javascript

Essentially I ask if we can apply the :nth-child pseudoElement function in :not pseudoElement results.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: :nth-child can't be used in this way.

Comment: True, you are right what I am searching is not a way to do it necessarily with nth child, maybe some different mechanism I am not aware of.
Not specifically for nth child but how to select on result of select maybe.. I am trying not to use JS for style and I am exploring the borders of this..

Comment: I think you hit the border.  You can add extra classes in your HTML to do this, but CSS won't do this kind of filtering.

Comment: if you know that you'll only have one or two `.Row--toIgnore`, you can probably come up with CSS sibling conditions that fake it, but if it's an unlimited number, your CSS file will end up infinitely long.

Comment: Please join chat: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130540/http-stackoverflow-com-q-41125044-877671